# Will extracting data from salesforce remove all data from salesforce

Tags: data-loader, dataloader.io

If I extract data from salesforce for an object using dataloader.io or dataloader, would it remove data too for that object from salesforce.

Comment: Not unless you delete it.

Comment: I thought the same thing when I first started, I simply did a small test and found out myself.....

Answer (score 7):

No, you would have to do a delete.  Extract with Dataloader is just a dump to a csv.  So if you just do an export and don't then do a delete you're fine.

Comment: If I use data management and use export for a custom object including attachmnets will it delete data from salesforce

Comment: I don't know of anyway to delete data from Salesforce, other than expressly clicking delete or running a delete in apex or a delete with any data integration tool.  I've never heard of just an export deleting data.